# Script to log temperature

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have been trying to write a BASH script to log my raspberry pi's temperature. My plan is to run it as a crontab every 15 mins or something. However I keep getting errors, I think it's something to do with me joining the strings together, I want 
DATE1;TEMP1
DATE2;TEMP2
etc. (a csv)

My code is;

```
 #!/bin/bash
vcgencmd measure_temp > /tmp/temp.txt
TEMP= grep -o [1-9][0-9]\.[0-9] /tmp/temp.txt
DATE= date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M
STR="$DATE"
echo $STR
STR+=";"
echo $STR
STR+="$TEMP"
echo $STR
echo $STR >> /home/pi/temp_hist.csv
```

All the echos are just me trying to figure out what's happening.

I would appreciate pointers for fixing this script as well as a better way to do it!

I originally posted it on the raspberry pi stack exchange - [Script to log temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31856/script-to-log-temperature) - But was told it should go here instead.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Is that space before `#!` a copy-paste error? If it's in your script, remove it.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that you have a space after the `=`:

```
TEMP= grep -o [1-9][0-9]\.[0-9] /tmp/temp.txt
```

That's wrong and breaks your script. The next issue is that you're assigning the commands themselves, as strings, to the variables and not their output:

```
$ foo=date
$ echo $foo
date
```

To run the command and save its output to a variable, you need to use `$(command)` or `` `command` ``:

```
$ foo=$(date)
$ echo $foo
Mon May 25 19:09:11 EEST 2015
```

You also have various other bits and pieces that can be improved. Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vcgencmd measure_temp > /tmp/temp.txt
## Avoid using UPPER CASE variable names since they
## can conflict with environmental variables. 
temp=$(grep -o "[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]" /tmp/temp.txt)
date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
## No need for another variable
printf "%s;%s\n" "$date" "$temp" >> /home/pi/temp_hist.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `vcgencmd measure_temp` will create a single fixed point number, this command may do what you want:

```
temp=$( vcgencmd measure_temp | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]' )
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M;${temp}" >> /home/pi/temp_hist.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a string and appending to it, just create the string directly:

```
➜  ~  DATE="1234"
➜  ~  TEMP="15"
➜  ~  STR="$DATE;$TEMP"
➜  ~  echo $STR
1234;15
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to Janis' answer. However, you might find `rrdtool` a better option for this kind of thing. It records its values in pre-determined time slots (or NV if the time slot is missed). It can then be used to create some very nice graphs, or output the data to XML or TSV. Here's a starter-tutorial: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrd-beginners.en.html